# "marker.getPosition is not a function" while markerclustering

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

The result is giving me this error: "TypeError: marker.getPosition is not a function".

I Did multiple search about the markerClustering but couldn't find any explanation for error!

My variable myMarkers is an array as asked in the documentation of MarkerClusterer.

If someone could help me, it would be much apreciated :)

```js
function initMap(){

    var maDataBase = [];
    var myMarkers = [];

    $.getJSON( "https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=MY-CONTRACT&apiKey=MY-API-KEY", function( data ) {
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        maDataBase.push(val);
        });
    }).done(function(){ 

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var myMap = $('.main')[0];
        var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var googleMap = new google.maps.Map(myMap, mapOptions);

        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++){

            myMarkers.push(new google.maps.LatLng(maDataBase[i].position.lat, maDataBase[i].position.lng));

            for (var x = 0, marker; x < myMarkers.length;x++){

                bounds.extend(myMarkers[i]);

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map : googleMap,
                    position: myMarkers[i],
                });
            }

        };

        googleMap.fitBounds(bounds);
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(googleMap, myMarkers,{imagePath: '../img/m'});

    });

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>JCDecaux</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main" id="main">

    </div>




    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-API-KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
    <script src="js/markerclusterer.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of `myMarkers.push(new google.maps.LatLng(maDataBase[i].position.lat, maDataBase[i].position.lng));` do `myMarkers.push(new google.maps.Marker(/*MarkerOptions object*/));`

Answer (score 1):

`myMarkers` isn't an array of `google.maps.Markers`.  The entries don't have a `getPosition` method.  Save the `google.maps.Marker` objects you create in an array and add that to the `MarkerClusterer`.